# Extract and display multiple strings in a single line

Tags: bash

I have a single line and i wanna extract/display (from bash) all entire strings starting by specific characters.

---

Single line to filter:

```
"ABC-3324545/":{"acc":"fff"},"ABC-652123/":{"acc":"sss"},"ABC-15642/":{"acc":"rrr"}...
```

---

Specific character to research in strings: 
ABC-

---

Display needed:

ABC-3324545
ABC-652123
ABC-15642

---

i think i need to combinate multiple cmd like grep awk sed, etc... but unfortunately, no result :(

curl -H "Token: xxxx" $URL | grep -o 'ABC-'

returns 
ABC-
ABC-
ABC-

curl -H "Token: xxxx" $URL | awk -F "PKI-" '{ print $1; '}
...don't match with what i wan't to do

Any idea plz?

Comment: What does it mean _to filter a line_. Furthermore, you need to show your attempts in solving the problem.

Comment: That input _kind of_ looks like JSON: is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data file:

```
$ cat abc.dat
"ABC-3324545/":{"acc":"fff"},"ABC-652123/":{"acc":"sss"},"ABC-15642/":{"acc":"rrr"}...
"DEF-3324545/":{"acc":"fff"},"DEF-652123/":{"acc":"sss"},"DEF-15642/":{"acc":"rrr"}...
```

Assuming the desired string **a)** starts with `ABC-` and **b)** ends before the next `/`, one `grep` idea:

```
$ grep -o "ABC-[^/]*" abc.dat
ABC-3324545
ABC-652123
ABC-15642
```

Where `[^/]*` says to match everything that is not a `/`, ie, match everything up to the next `/`.